# How to make register command on discord.js and mongodb atlas?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, discord, discord.js

I want to save my discord member data using register command, please help me!!

**bot.js**

```
 client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.content === "!register, ign:<input from member>, level:<input from member>"){
    const newProfileSchema = new ProfileSchema({
      discordid: "Discord Member Username",
      ign: "<input from member>",
      level: "<input from member>",
    })
  }
})
```

And this is the schema look like
**Schema.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
  discordid: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  ign: {
    type: String
  },
  level: {
    type: Number
  }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('profile', ProfileSchema);
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking. You're providing schema file, but you don't even have the command setup to parse the arguments? You'll need to update the original question to clarify what you're asking and limit the code snippets to what's needed to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood, because your question is not clear at all
You need to add collection to your db using mongoose when command `!register` is run.

```
const ign = args.slice(1).join(" ")
const level = args.slice.... // same thing 
const newSchemaprofile = new Schema({
       discordid: message.author.id,
       ign: ign,
       level: level,
}).save();
message.reply({content: 'Your data is saved'})
```

This is how you save data with [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)